# Can't type in transfer fee amount

Tags: technical-issues, ios, fifa-12

I can't type in the transfer fee in this screen:

[image]
I type in an amount but it doesn't change the Transfer Fee amount in the "Make an offer" screen.

Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried tapping the white field before typing? Also, it looks like your keyboard isn't set to English. Can you change it to English and see if it works?

Comment: It all came down to the order in which you pressed the two "OK"-buttons. Thx for helping out, though :)

Comment: Why don't you put this as the answer to your own question? This will help other players who might encounter the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the OK in the native iPad keyboard first, then press the large OK in the middle.

Then everything should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution I found:

For some reason if I tried to make and offer on a player through the Shortlist I was unabled to set a transfer fee, even when following timkl's steps.

However, if I went into the **Transfer Market**, selected the player there, and then made an offer I WAS able to set a transfer fee.

Guess something is wrong with the shortlist, as I tried multiple times to no avail, but it worked instantly when I went in through the **Transfer Market**.